# "unable to run adb.exe , check your android sdk installation and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT" showing when i am running flutter doctor

Tags: android-studio, flutter

when i am running flutter doctor in my command promt and error pops up saying

"connected device : (the doctor check crashed )
due to an error, the doctor check did not complete.
exception: unable to run"adb",check your android sdk installation and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT enviroment variable:
c:\users\sayan\appdata\local\android\sdk\platfotm-tools\adb.exe"

i dont know hoe to solve this error i will be greatfull if anybody helps me to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the path of "Android SDK" you downloaded to "environment variables" as "ANDROID_HOME";
also inside the sdk there are 2 folders `platform-tools` and `tools` => add their paths to "Path" in "environment variables";

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue solved by Updating platrorm-tools from SDK-Manager.